# Haskell function that return the next prime number after given n

Tags: haskell

Learning Haskell. Trying to write a function called `nextPrime n` that will return the next prime number after `n`.

I have the following:

```
-- Generate a list of all factors of n
factors :: Integral a => a -> [a]
factors n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0]

-- True iff n is prime
isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPrime n = factors n == [1, n]
```

So far the function is set up like so:

```
nextPrime :: Integral a => a -> a
nextPrime n =
```

I presume I have to do a sort of while loop maybe but not sure how. I am totally new to functional programming. Any help is appreciated

Comment: look at [`dropWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:dropWhile) and [`head`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head)

Comment: [find](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:find) is an option too ^^

Comment: If this is homework you should try this using recursion. The first step of the assignment ought to be to think clearly about what you're trying to do and state it declaratively: "nextPrime after n is n if n isPrime, otherwise it is the nextPrime after n+1" (this may or may not be precisely what you mean by "next prime after n"). The second step is to translate to haskell which involves learning some basic syntax (hint: "is" becomes `=`). See the info section of the haskell tag on SO for resources.

Comment: the way I understand it *after n* would imply that `nextPrime n > n` in any case so `nextPrime n = n+1 IIF n+1 is prime`

Comment: @jberryman "nextPrime after n is n if n isPrime" n is absolutely not after n, nextPrime after n should always start the search with n + 1.

Comment: I don't believe the spec is at all clear ;-) perhaps OP only stated it that way because he was imagining it being called with a non-prime? Regardless, I think op should implement the function I described, name it appropriately, and possibly call it with a helper on `n+1`.

Comment: @jberryman yeah now that you put it like that, "nextPrime" can be interpreted as "get me the prime after this one".

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that `nextPrime n` means "get me the first prime number that's greater than n".

Here's an idea:

```
nextPrime :: Integral a => a -> a
nextPrime n = nextPrime' (n + 1)
 where nextPrime' m = ...
```

You want to fill in the blanks for `nextPrime'`. Here's a hint:

```
fun n = if n <= 0 
        then 0 
        else n + fun (n - 1)
```

This is a recursive function that calculates the sum `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n`, though it does it starting with `n` and going down from there. `nextPrime'` will have to go up.